# How to reproduce this shape

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a `RecyclerView` and I want to add a half line, picture & half line before it. However I have no idea of how to reproduce it. Can you please help me to get a similar shape?

[image: half line + pictogram + half line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="lala"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty option:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tv_center_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_center_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#C8C1C1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_center_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="#C8C1C1"/>
    <size android:width="250dp"/>
    <size android:height="8dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#C8C1C1"/>
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```